# Puppet File resource runs despite Exec unless

Tags: puppet

I'm applying a local manifest to test an `exec` and `file` resource:

```
class test_file {   
  exec { "touch /tmp/testfile":
    path   => ["/bin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/usr/sbin"],
    unless => "test -d /tmp 2>/dev/null",
  }

  file { "/tmp/success":
    mode    => "0777",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "staff",
    source  => "file:///Users/Shared/success",
    require => Exec["touch /tmp/testfile"],
  }
}
```

**What I expect to happen:** 
The `exec` runs and exits because the `unless` statement returns 0, so the file resource never runs and neither file is created in `/tmp`.

**What Actually happens:** 
The `file` resource always runs, and copies the "success" file to `/tmp`

I've run this on macOS 10.11 and 10.12 with both puppet agent 4.10 and 5.3.2 ... with the same results. I'm simply trying to run a conditional that says don't copy a file if some command exits successful. Any insights or directions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are misundersanding how Puppet works.

The [require](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/metaparameter.html#require) metaparameter declares the order in which resources should be applied.* Given your manifest, Puppet only promises that the Exec resource - *if it is applied at all* - will always be applied before the File resource.

There is another metaparameter, [subscribe](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/metaparameter.html#subscribe). If a resource *subscribes* to another resource, then Puppet tries to "refresh" that resource if the resource it is subscribed to changes state.

Unfortunately, you can't use that here, because File resources ignore "refresh events".

What you can do, although it's a bit ugly, is:

```
class test_file () {
  Exec {
    path => ["/bin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/usr/sbin"],
  }

  exec { "touch /tmp/testfile":
    unless  => "test -d /tmp 2>/dev/null",
  }

  exec { "cp /Users/Shared/success /tmp/success":
    subscribe   => Exec["touch /tmp/testfile"],
    refreshonly => true,
  }
}
```

* The require metaparameter also prevents a second resource from being applied at all if the first resource fails to apply. See the [failed dependencies](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_relationships.html#failed-dependencies) section in the docs.

Comment: He is only doing this for training though, so I don't know if he actually wants to do this contrived scenario in a real environment. In that situation he probably would have a `file` do the first action and an `exec` do the second.

Comment: This is not quite right.  The `File` having a `require` reqlationship on the `Exec` not only establishes order of application, but also prevents the `File` from being applied at all if an attempt to apply the `Exec` is made and fails.  But of course the `Exec` failing is different from it not being applied on account of already being in sync (as determined, in this case, via its `unless` command).

Comment: I added a footnote about this.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as you mentioned 'required' only sets order .. it started to make sense. I was thinking more of a if/else type condition. So I ended up writing an external fact that deploys with my module. If simply checks for the condition I want and sets a variable to "installed" or "uninstalled". Then I use an "If" condition in my manifest before my exec. This works beautifully.